# How to integrate Drive API to my Java app (in which file?)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I am a newbie android developer and need to create an app that uploads a .zip file to Google Drive, Downloaded the API but where do I add the code, and how? Please provide a code example.

Comment: Explain more on what you did and how are you trying to achieve it.

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by "downloaded the api"?

Drive has some pretty good documentation on instantiating the drive client as well as an activity to demonstrate different use cases.  These may be all the examples you need.

[Drive Examples](https://github.com/gsuitedevs/android-samples/tree/master/drive/demos/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/drive/sample/demo)

Answer (score 0):

You can find good examples in the documentation for the Drive API 
https://developers.google.com/drive/android/examples/

Or look here: https://developers.google.com/drive/android/intro to find some more explanation about how it all works